# Can't seem to get mutation to work Prisma GraphQL

Tags: javascript, graphql, prisma

I am having trouble getting a mutation to work in the GraphQL Playground, it always returns `null`

[image: GraphQL Playground]

[image: Mutation]

[image: Resolver]

[image: Schema]

I've been wrangling with this for the past 2 days and can't seem to get the object to show up in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be returning anything from your resolver (image #3).

```js
function createDay(parent, args, context, info) {
  return context.prisma.createDay({...args})
}
```